# sql query from many table in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have an mp3 downloading site and I want to create a search page, but I am in simple confusion. I have two tables, one that stores movie details like `movie name` and `movie cast`, and another one where all the songs of movies are stored. The structure of two tables is shown below:

```
Table 1: name categories
column :5
id,cat,cast,year,type
here id is primary key
  cat is album/movie name
  cast is all actores details of movie
  year is releasing year and type is movie type

Table 2: files
column :4
id,cat,preview,file
```

Here my user can search with any keywords, and I can extract rows by sql query but here are two tables so I am confused what to do? 
The user can input previews from `table` and can enter cat, type, cast, type and year from `table 1`.

Comment: I really can't understand the part after the tables structure sir, for sure you can use an SQL join for this, but please explain more. You want to search with keyword in which fields? I think `categories.cat` and `categories.cast`, `files.cat` are some of them.

Comment: That's what SQL joins are for. Any SQL tutorial should explain how to join tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is not clear, But using join in query is not that complicated as you think, try and learn. Good luck

```
SELECT Category.cat, Category.cast, Category.year, Category.Type, File.preview, File.file
FROM category As Category
LEFT JOIN files As File On Category.cat = File.cat 
WHERE Category.cat LIKE '%search%' OR Category.cast LIKE '%search%'
OR File.preview LIKE '%search%'
```

etc